# Uncrustify obj-c: Newline before and after call to super, interface declaration and implementation declaration

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uncrustify

How can I add newline after call to super with uncrustify

**Current:**

```
- (void)someFunction
{
   [super someFunction];
   more stuff;
   and more stuff;
}
```

**Desired:**

```
- (void)someFunction
{
   [super someFunction];

   more stuff;
   and more stuff;
}
```

And how can I add newline before and after interface declaration and implementation declaration

**Current:**

```
@interface SCLoginScreenViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *someView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *anotherView;
@end
@implementation SCLoginScreenViewController
- (void)someFunction
{
}
```

**Desired:**

```
@interface SCLoginScreenViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *someView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *anotherView;

@end

@implementation SCLoginScreenViewController

- (void)someFunction
{
}
```

- I am using BBUncrustifyPlugin and UncrustifyX

Comment: Seems like, need to create a Plugin which can do this !!

Comment: @RoNiT, There is already a plugin - BBUncrustifyPlugin. The question is which option out of 250 to use

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Uncrustify doesn't support any of these features at the moment.<sup>1</sup>

The only "new line after" options that are shown below.

(Two not included in the screenshot are: `Newline count after variable definition block` and `Newline count after variable definition block not at the top of a function body`)

[image]

There are some other options in the "newlines" section. But again, none of them match your case:

(`Newline after while` missing from screenshots)

[image]
[image]

---

<sup>1. *I'm using version2.1.1, I believe this is the latest*</sup>